# Load image from custom server address laravel encore admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

I'm using Laravel encore admin library.

In user database, my image string is stored as **"/imageName.ext"**

And in **$show** of controller, I am showing image as :

`$show->field('image', __('Image'))->image('localhost/storage/images');`

Documentation tells that image() methods takes three arguments as *$server, $width, $length*.
But despite giving server address in image(), I gets server address as:

> *http://localhost:8000/storage/imageName.ext*

which should be:

> *http://localhost:8000/storage/images/imageName.ext*